# call a specific url with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I want to create a get request in rspec.

```
    get :exec, {:query=>"bla",
      :id => "something",
      :user_id => "user"
    }
```

This builds a URL like: `/user/query/something/exec?query=bla`

The thing is that my controller checks the request it gets and the url must look like:
`/user/query/something/_XXX_/exec?query=bla`

How can I do something like this in rspec? (The XXX is hard-coded in the routes.rb file.)

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the ruby-on-rails tag.  If that was in error, we'll remove it.

Answer (score 17):

I'm assuming you're referring to a controller spec.

When you pass in a hash like in your example, the keys will be matched against the variables in your routes. For any key that doesn't match the route, the key/value pair will be appended as a query string.

For example, suppose you have this in your spec:

```
get :exec, :query => 'foo', :id => '1', :user_id => 42
```

And you have this in your routes (Rails 3 style):

```
match '/exec/:user_id/:id' => 'whatever#exec'
```

The spec will then substitute in the key/value pairs you've given and simulate a request with the following path:

```
/exec/42/1?query=foo
```

So, to wire up your specs to your routes, just make sure you're properly matching the variable names in your routes to the params in your spec request.

Comment: The main problem of my question is the "XXX" - it is -as said- hardcoded in the routes file (I'm doing this because I need named routes) so there is no :lang parameter, something/XXX/exec?query=bla and something/YYY/exec?query=bla are vaild urls and only one of them (the first in the routes file) can be created via rspecs get...

Comment: I don't know if RSpec makes it possible to choose a particular named route over another. I believe it will always just pick the first route that matches your params. I think this is by design: RSpec wants you to test things in isolation, e.g. your controller isolated from your routes. I suppose you could always hack it by stubbing out the method that returns the request URL.