# calling specific url in Rspec in integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm trying to do the following in rspec (know that I shouldn't have hardcoded value) in an integration test:

```
get '/api/get-other-items?id=5109'
```

The closest I could find was: [call a specific url with rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462688/call-a-specific-url-with-rspec) but it selects only a single item. I have tried the following:

```
get :controller => 'api', :action => 'get-other-items', :id => '5109'
get 'api/get-other-items', :id => '5109'
```

These are giving me a `bad argument(expected URI object or URI string)`

If I run as

```
get get_other_items, :id => '5109' q
```

I get

```
undefined local variable or method `get_other_items' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x007f938fd65590>
```

but the route does exist:

```
Mon Jan 23$ rake routes | grep get_other_items
get_other_items     /api/get-other-items(.:format)      {:controller=>"api", :action=>"get_other_items"}
```

How would I perform this simple get?

thx

**update for answer 1 comment**
here's the rspec code in question:

```
it "testing getting other items for menu item" do
  get get_other_items_path(:id => '5109')
  JSON.parse(response.body)
  puts response.body
```

Mon Jan 23$ rspec requests/get_other_items_spec.rb

```
F

Failures:

  1) GetOtherItems testing getting other items for menu item
   Failure/Error: JSON.parse(response.body)
   JSON::ParserError:
   743: unexpected token at 'this is not found          '
     # ./requests/get_other_items_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 13.57 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:
```

Answer (score 0):

The call should be `get get_other_items_path(:id => 5109)` - you need to add `path` to the name of the route, or `url` if you want the full URL instead of a relative path.

Comment: thx but still getting an error, looks like this isn't being picked up in the router as my 404 is coming back. Is there a way to output the route that it will be 'using' (ie obviously not making an http call).

Comment: Can you post the routes.rb contents?

Comment: thx - I know this is obviously an issue with me:   `match '/api/get-other-items' => 'api#get_other_items', :as => :get_other_items`

Comment: The route is ok - can you post the exact error log you're getting?

Comment: updated above with code / problem, the 'this is not found' is the 404

Comment: The routes are fine, this is no longer a routing issue. The 404 error is most likely caused by an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception. Look into the code of the `get_other_items` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your route doesn't look like it's taking a `:id` as a parameter, if you want to send an `:id` I would expect to see the following:

```
get_other_items /api/get-other-items/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"api", :action=>"get_other_items"}
```

Given the structure of your generated route I assume that you are using `match` to define the route (There is no HTTP verb in your route). To fix it try:

```
match 'api/get-other-items/:id' => 'api#get_other_items'
```

If instead you are using restful routes then it looks like you have specified a `collection` route rather than a `member` route. A `collection` route doesn't take an `:id` and is designed to return many records of the type you have specified. To make it a `member` route use the following:

```
resources :api do
  get 'get_other_items', :on => :member
end
```

Once you get this working you should be able to try the following in rspec in your `ApiController` spec:

```
get :get_other_items, :id => '5109'
```

If neither of these options work please post your routes entry so we can try something else.